# What database should I use that does not need an application to be installed

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Is there any database that does not required to installed the application at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

No. Any database server requires a specialized client to connect to it.

It might be a simple command-line client (e.g. `mysql`) or a GUI (e.g. phpMyAdmin), but it's always needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `SQLite`. You can compile the source code of the `SQLite` library with your application, which then provides your application with the capabilities of creating, reading, and writing databases.

Essentially your application becomes the client and there are no additional dependencies.

More info: https://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html